# Accept/Reject Whatsapp call programtically?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is there any way to accept/reject Whatsapp call programtically? There is notification listener api to read notifications. One way could be read WhatsApp notification for call and select accept/reject from notification actions. Is it possible or there any other way which can do it better?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)